# Handling UTF-8 encoded strings between std::wstring and std::string

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8

I am using two libraries one that stores UTF-8 strings in `std::wstring` and another stores strings ( UTF-8) in `std::string`.
What is the best / efficient method I can use to pass strings between the two libraries.
I am currently on Windows using Visual C++ v9 Express but would prefer a portable solution.

Comment: When you say "stores UTF-8 string in std::wstring", what are you referring to exactly?  Did you actually mean UTF-16? std::wstring is not suitable for storing UTF-8 octets (but std::string is).

Comment: @Remy Lebeau It is an ODBC library that retrieves UTF-8 data from a database and delivers the data in std::wstrings.
How the data is actually stored inside the library I really don't know.

Comment: It does not matter how the library manipulates data internally.  What is important is how it passes that data to/from your code.  If it is using `std::wstring` for that, then it is likely using/expecting UTF-16.  Which makes sense, as UTF-8 and UTF-16 are just different encodings of the same Unicode character set.  The database could be using any charset it wanted other than UTF-8, and ODBC would likely handle it internally and still utilize UTF-16 when passing data to/from you for consistency.

Comment: If you retreive a character outside the ASCII range e.g. `à` using your ODBC library, what is the decimal or hex value of wstring[0]?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you mean UTF-16 and not UTF-8 for `std::wstring`, you will have to encode/decode the strings from one library to the other. I'm not sure if/what the STL provides for that, but you can use Windows's own `MultiByteToWideChar()` and `WideCharToMultiByte()` functions to convert between UTF-8 and UTF-16 with just a few lines of code.  You could then wrap that into your own functions so you can replace the logic when you find something more portable, eg:

```
std::wstring Utf8ToUtf16(const std::string &s)
{
    std::wstring ret;
    int len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, s.c_str(), s.length(), NULL, 0);
    if (len > 0)
    {
      ret.resize(len);
      MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, s.c_str(), s.length(), const_cast<wchar_t*>(ret.c_str()), len);
    }
    return ret;
}

std::string Utf16ToUtf8(const std::wstring &s)
{
    std::string ret;
    int len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, s.c_str(), s.length(), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (len > 0)
    {
      ret.resize(len);
      WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, s.c_str(), s.length(), const_cast<char*>(ret.c_str()), len, NULL, NULL);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Note that this is Windows specific, but UTF-16 hopefully means Windows here.

Comment: Will not compile as `c_str` returns a const C-string. But +1 for being on the right way.

Comment: UTF-16 is not Windows-specific. The only Windows-specific portion is the API functions used.  Like I said, this was just to demonstrate how to do it.  When the OP finds a more portable solution, he/she can replace the API functions without having to rewrite the rest of his/her code.

Comment: I added a couple of `const_cast` casts now.

Comment: UTF-16 itself is not Windows-specific, but the assumption that `wchar_t` is UTF-16 *is* Windows-specific.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/). It is portable and has a lot of converters between encodings

Comment: Too big for my current needs. My program is less than 400KB, statically linked to the runtime. ICU will likely more than double the size and I am not sure if I can statically link against it.

Comment: If not ICU then `iconv`. That's even POSIX.