# How to set a text in gtk containing wide characters?

Tags: c++, character-encoding, gtk

I'm struggling trying to set a wchar_t array in my Gtk/ c++ application. For some unknown reason the Gtk methods do not have a overloaded form which support wchar_t arrays but only gchar ones.

I've read couple articles which made me wonder that it may be a variable-width encoding concern, which is set in regular UTF-8. I'm trying to do something like:

```
std::wstring propertiesText;

/*
String Manipulation...     
*/

gtk_label_set_text( (GtkLabel*)_propertiesLabel, propertiesText.c_str() );
```

And as I said said the compiler is complaining that the wchar_t is not supported by this method.

If you can clear my issue in any form or even explain something about these variable-width encoding/ wide-characters relation.

Answer (score 3):

GTK is built above [Glib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/). And Glib has deeply supposed that all strings are [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoded. Also [wchar_t](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wchar_t#wchar_t) is not very portable (on some compilers, it might be 16 bits, on others, it could be 32 bits). So you should avoid using `wchar_t` or `std::wstring` in your code. BTW, you could be interested in [Gtkmm](http://www.gtkmm.org/en/index.html) if you are coding in C++ (then consider using [Glib::ustring](http://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/unstable/classGlib_1_1ustring.html)-s).

If you absolutely need to use `std::wstring` for some reason you have to make the (perhaps costly) conversions to and from Glib UTF-8 encoded string explicitly by hand.

Comment: To do the latter, you can use [iconv](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/iconv.h.html) (it's included in glibc and also available as a [separate library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/)). On Windows, you can also use [WideCharToMultiByte](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6864228/249167).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Basile.
I ended up solving this problem with a simple solution,
g_utf8_strlen (const gchar, gssize max);
which counts the string on the utf8 format. 
Hope this can save time for the next person who stumble with this problem.