# urlDecode - php function in c++

Tags: c++, urldecode

I have urlDecode function.

But when i'm decoding some string like:
`P%C4%99dz%C4%85cyJele%C5%84`

I get output: `PÄ™dzÄ…cyJeleĹ„`

Of course this is not correct output. I think its broken because there are Polish chars.

I try to set in compilator:
`Use Unicode Character Set`
or `Use Multi-Byte Character Set`

I try to do that using wstrings but i have a lot of errors :|
I suppose that i should use `wstring` not `string` but could you tell me how? There is not easier way to solve my problem? (i listen a lot about wstring and string and litte dont understand - wstring should not use on linux, but i have Windows)

//link to my functions at bottom

http://bogomip.net/blog/cpp-url-encoding-and-decoding/

**//EDIT**

When i change all string to wstring, fstream->wfstream

It still problem look:

`z%C5%82omiorz` - this wstring (from file ) != złomiorz , but this function print me L"z197130omiorz"

what is 197130 ? How to fix that ?:0

Comment: This is a UTF-8 string with the urlEncode method, so what you are getting from urlDecode is a UTF-8 string. Windows does not handle UTF-8 natively, you need to convert it to whatever character set you are using.

Comment: @n.m i have to convert string or wstring from urlDecode ? Can you show some example, please :) I never do that :(

Comment: urdDecode returns a string. You can try to convert that string from UTF-8 encoding to a wstring. Try a function from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864064/handling-utf-8-encoded-strings-between-stdwstring-and-stdstring).

Comment: @n.m. okey, so i dont have to read file in wstring ?
Only url_decode to wstring, and keep this data in wstring 'oh sorry, only decode urldecode output from string to wstring