# Passing std::string with dllexport

Tags: c++, interop, dllimport

I'm trying to make some sort of C++ "bridge" to connect an unmanaged C++ dll on one end (without modifying their code) to a C# Wrapper which uses DllImport for various imports.

I was able to pass a C# string to my bridge using char pointers, but the receiving Dll needs to receive std::string, so I tried with `std::string(foo);` with no luck, it always gets transformed into weird characters.

The structure is the following :

**C# Wrapper**

```
[DllImport(@"Bridge.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void initDetector(string foo, int something = 0);
```

**C++ Bridge**

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void initCppClass(char* foo, int something)
{
    std::string bar = std::string(foo);
    std::cout << bar << std::endl; //Returns "foo"
    instance = new CppClass(bar, something);
}
```

**C++ Imported DLL (not allowed to change code here)**

```
CppClass::CppClass(std::string foo, int something)
{
    std::cout << foo << std::endl; //Returns garbage
}
```

*Note that this constructor is for demonstration purposes only, as I cannot disclose the original code.*

I originally tried passing the char* directly to the constructor but that didn't work either. Is there something I'm missing here ?

Comment: This can't be a C# question because you can't make a std::string in C#. So you must be asking how to get your bridge dll to pass a std::string to the original dll. Right? That's going to require your bridge dll to link dynamically to the same runtime as the original dll. Does it?

Comment: Exactly, the C# part was just to clarify what I was trying to do. I'm not sure what you mean about the linking but what I did was add the headers and the libs to my project and it seems to go through because the integer named 'something' has the correct value when I print it

Comment: The C# and the pinvoke is a distraction. You need to know how the original dll is linking to the rtl. The issues are all documented. Have you read the documentation?

Comment: I'm not sure how to get that kind of information. I'm trying to import [this library](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/README.md#how-to-use-yolo-as-dll) using Visual Studio if that helps. The exported code is in the yolo_v2_class files fyi. All I did was include the header files and the required libs to the linker.

Comment: Calling a C++ function that takes standard C++ library class objects as arguments is never not a problem.  C++ does not run in a VM and does not use a jitter, there is no authority that demands the layout of a class object.  Only you.  You must use the **exact** same compiler version with the exact same settings as was used to build the DLL.  Something as basic as using the Debug build of your C++ glue is enough to cause corruption.

Comment: If you can you should find an alternative to this dll. Its going to tie you to a single compiler version forever.

Comment: The problem is that's it's the only known library available for this and we've been able to use it through making some changes in the original source, which we want to avoid now in case the owner updates it. Thanks you both for your help though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is different string encoding.

Try adding `CharSet = CharSet.Ansi` in C#, like this:

```
[DllImport(@"Bridge.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
```

However, please read the documentation of that C++ dll API. A lot of C++ code, especially if that’s cross-platform code, expect UTF8-encoded strings. If that’s your case, instead change the bridge to

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void initCppClass(const wchar_t* foo, int something)
```

And write code to convert the string from UTF16-encoded C pointer into UTF8-encoded std::string, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6864228/126995) for an example.

**Update:** another possible reason is different STL, or different CRT. When you pass std::string or any other STL objects objects across DLL boundaries, you have to use same compiler & same version of it, same build settings for (e.g. in VC++, std::strings memory layout differs between debug and release builds), and also both DLLs must link to CRT dynamically., e.g. `Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)`

Comment: Nope. Read the comments. The issues are in the bridge dll. There should be any C# in the question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Nope. See what I wrote after the “Update”.

Also on all versions of Windows where .NET framework is supported, the default charset for unmanaged imports is Unicode. And “Bridge.dll”, as opposed to e.g. “bridge.so”, tells that they’re likely on Windows. Which makes what I’ve wrote before the “Update” still relevant.

Comment: It's the bit before the update that isn't relevant. Default CharSet for pinvoke on Windows is ANSI for what it's worth. So wrong as well as not relevant.

Comment: @Soonts Alright, turns out I totally overlooked the fact that the given dll was compiled in **Release** mode and didn't think of adjusting my wrapper to **Release** as well because I wanted to debug it so it was set to **Debug** mode. I admit I'm pretty stupid for not figuring this out ... Thanks, your answer made me check every little parameter until I figured it out :)

Comment: @FlawTECH Glad I helped. BTW, that’s why I like to build all dependencies from a single visual studio solution & setup dependencies between projects: this way it’s harder to make such errors with incompatible configurations or platforms.